# Changing OS X desktop background image scaling mode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, position, scaling, desktop-wallpaper

I've been working on a project that changes the desktop image, which I've been accomplishing like so:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setDesktopImageURL:fileURL forScreen:[NSScreen mainScreen] options:[NSDictionary dictionary] error:&error];
```

This works, but gives me no control over the scaling. I'd like to be able to choose scaling options programatically as you can in the UI (fill screen, fit to screen, stretch to fill screen, center, tile), but I can find no documentation explaining how to do so. Worse than that, calling the above method always resets the scaling to "fill screen".

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `NSWorkspaceDesktopImageScalingKey` in the `option` parameter. Here's the possible values:

`NSImageScaleProportionallyDown`

If it is too large for the destination, scale the image down while preserving the aspect ratio.

`NSImageScaleAxesIndependently`

Scale each dimension to exactly fit destination.
This setting does not preserve the aspect ratio of the image.

`NSImageScaleNone`

Do not scale the image.

`NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown`

Scale the image to its maximum possible dimensions while both staying within the destination area and preserving its aspect ratio.

Declared in NSCell.h.

Comment: Bingo! Works like a charm. This was a blocker, so I very much appreciate your help. Thanks again!

Comment: I know this is quite old, but is there a way to set the "Tile" scaling option? Using `desktopImageOptionsForScreen:`, I can't see any difference when "Tile" is selected vs the default "Fill".